# Sockets will just die and not reconnect after some time

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I wrote this module for a chat room, and whenever the socket dies it should try to reconnect.  However, I've noticed that after around 10 or 15 minutes, the socket will stop trying to reconnect.  Why could this happen? My code is as follows:

```
bool Socket::Connection::_connect(int delay_ms)
{
    closesocket(sock);

    hostEntry = gethostbyname(host);

    if( !hostEntry )
    {
        //Couldn't resolve our host
        return false;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if( sock == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        //Invalid socket
        return false;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN serverInfo;
    serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_addr = *(LPIN_ADDR)*hostEntry->h_addr_list;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(port);

    int nret = SOCKET_ERROR;

    while( (nret == SOCKET_ERROR) )
    {
        nret = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&serverInfo, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if( nret == SOCKET_ERROR )
            Sleep(delay_ms);
        if( running == false )
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void Socket::Connection::start()
{
    u_long iMode = 1;
    fd_set rdevents;
    struct timeval tv;

    while( 1 ) //Outer, connection loop
    {
        if( !_connect(RECONNECT_TIME) )
            continue;

        int nret = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &iMode);
        if( nret != NO_ERROR )
            continue;

        //if( onconnect != NULL )
            //onconnect(sock);

        while( 1 ) //Inner, command loop
        {
            FD_ZERO( &rdevents );
            FD_SET( sock, &rdevents );
            tv.tv_sec = 8;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            nret = select(0, &rdevents, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if( nret == SOCKET_ERROR )
            {
                break;
            }
            else if( nret > 0 )
            {
                if( FD_ISSET(sock, &rdevents) )
                {
                    char buf[1024];
                    nret = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);

                    if( nret == 0 ) 
                        break;

                    if( onrecv != NULL ) onrecv(sock, buf, nret);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(sock);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see the code where it says 'if socket dies, reconnect'. I do see the code that says 'when I ask you to connect, try connection in a loop till that succeeds'. They are two different things. Is there something else somewhere in your code that keeps calling start() in a loop? The command loop in the start() function would be 'breaking' out on socket errors .... and I do not see any attempt to reconnect after that break out.

Comment: Yes, on a socket error the inner loop would break and the outer loop would call it again.

Comment: I see that now. But then

1. Why have a continue in the outer loop just after _connect? That may result in infinite loop, which is likely to bring down your comp. What if gethostbyname() has a permanent failure?
2. The loop inside _connect() is already infinite on socket connection; you may not need the continue after all. The errors before connect are fatal and not likely to succeed on subsequent tries. 
3. This may be the problem - You MUST close the socket once your receive a valid socket descriptor. Your code is connecting multiple times but closing only once.